# how to convert PPT to jpg in web application?

Tags: document

Anyone know of a way to use PHP on an apache server to convert ppt slides into images on the server?
How would you go about installing it on the server?
What if installing a program on the server is not possible?

Comment: if installing a program on the server is not possible, then you'd have to do it in your browser, which is way more complicate.

Comment: It's multiple questions. How to do it and how to do it with limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unoconv might do it for you.

http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/

```
unoconv <filename>.ppt <filename>.pdf
convert <filename>.pdf <filename>.jpg
```

You need of course do some php-coding to use it in the background.

Comment: Found this question asking how to do it in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379188/executing-unoconv-command-using-php